# @ngtools/webpack - Cannot find module 'enhanced-resolve'

Tags: angular, webpack

when using @ngtools/webpack in a project, getting this error, I am using npm as the dev platform

Answer (score 5):

For some reason @ngtools/webpack is not referencing **enhanced-resolve** module.

install the dependency separately

```js
npm install enhanced-resolve --save
```